# Как вывести данные вложенных словарей

Tags: c#, словари, for, foreach

```
public static void OutputForm(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> dictForms)
{
    foreach (var i in dictForms.Keys)
    {
        foreach (var j in dictForms.Values)
        {
            foreach (var k in j)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i + " " + k.Key + " " + k.Value);

            };
        }
    }
}
```

Есть словарь со вложенным словарем. Необходимо перебрать все данные, и вывести их (можно в столбик). Я попробовал вывести через 3 цикла foreach, но уже на втором цикле всё начинает ломаться, и вместо упорядоченных выводов, они начинаю пересекаться между собой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем тебе 3 цикла foreach? Для каждого ключа первого словаря ты проходишься по каждому значению первого словаря, а потом ещё и по каждому входу второго словаря.
У тебя всего 2 уровня вложенности, значит и цикла надо всего 2:

```cs
foreach(var a in dict)
{
    foreach(var b in a.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{a.Key}, {b.Key}: {b.Value}");
    }
}
```

Да и вообще лучше:

```cs
foreach(var a in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{a.Key}: {{{string.Join(", ", a.Value.Select(e => $"{e.Key}: {e.Value}"))}}}");
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое